# Saved camera parameters when restored shows different view in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are using similar code as below -

```
// Get camera params from viewer and save it
let camParams = oViewer.getViewArrayFromCamera();

// Do something - rotate, zoom, pan etc

// Restore the view as it was
oViewer.setViewFromArray(camParams);
```

This works for some views, but it is not restoring the exact view in some cases.

We have a sample code written inside one of the extracted models from http://extract.autodesk.io which shows this problem.
We can send the sample code on the support email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggest by **Bryan Huang** I tried using **viewer state** and it worked fine

```
// Get viewer state and save it
let viewerState = oViewer.getState();

// Do something - rotate, zoom, pan etc

// Restore the view as it was
oViewer.restoreState(viewerState);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to save and restore views would be to use the `navigation` interface:

```
const pos = NOP_VIEWER.navigation.getPosition(); //save current camera position
const target = NOP_VIEWER.navigation.getTarget(); //save current camera target
NOP_VIEWER.navigation.setView(pos,target) //restore
```

Or simply restore Viewer's state if you don't mind other states getting through

Comment: Hi @Bryan Huang,

Thank you for your prompt reply.

We are in 3D environment, so I am sure setting only position and target will not be sufficient.

Also, some more information - 

We are trying to do this for Markup2D feature that is somewhat similar to that explained here - 
https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html

We noticed that the RCDB demo for above feature has the same bug of resetting camera. Could you please check?

Comment: What's the bug exactly? What are the steps to reproduce it?

Comment: Hi Bryan,
restoring ViewerState works.

The problem can be seen in the RCDB forge demo here - 
https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598d7ec14cabf2c1f4dec948

Try and save few markups. When you are view mode, and click on those save markups one by one, you can see that the view changes, but not to the exact view settings. The markup looks displaced and the view has different camera.

Comment: Tks will try and fix that - track my progress [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/issues/91)